# First Column won't Show Percentage

Tags: python, debugging, graph, label, axis

I have a bug somewhere in this code but cannot seem to find it. The first column is not showing the percentage. Should be a quick fix!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series(
    [8, 24, 21, 23, 24],
    index = ["Your Plan", "Benchmark", "Region", "Industry", "Size"]
)

#Set descriptions:
plt.title("INSERT TITLE HERE, PLEASE")
plt.ylabel('Percentage of EEs Waiving')

#Set tick colors:
ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='black')

#Plot the data:
my_colors = ['#ffc000','#305496', '#8ea9db', '#b4c6e7', '#D9E1F2']  #red, green, blue, black, etc.

s.plot(
    kind="bar",
    color=my_colors,
)

# Rotate the desired axis (or undo the rotation)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=0)

# Set the Y Axis Limits
ax.set_ylim([0,100])

#Adds data labels to top of bars
for p in ax.patches[1:]:
    h = p.get_height()
    x = p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.
    if h != 0:
        ax.annotate("%g" % p.get_height()+'%', xy=(x,h), xytext=(0,8), rotation=0,
                    textcoords="offset points", ha="center", va="bottom")

plt.show()
plt.savefig("PlanOffered.png")
```

And, if you could also add a line in between the "Your Plan" and Benchmark Columns to separate the columns that would be great! Much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop which `Adds data labels to top of bars` starts with `1st` element instead of `0th`. Change it to

```
for p in ax.patches:
```

and it will show the % label for the `0th` value.

To add a vertical line between `0th` and `1st` bar you can plot `axvline` at `x=0.5`

```
line = plt.axvline(x=0.5)
```

For further styling of the line please refer to properties in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html), i.e.

- `line.linestyle='dashed'`
- `line.color = 'black'`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Any chance we can get the line to be black, faded (partially transparent) and in a dash line form?